# how to get django coverage report in single html file

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am running my unit test cases and want to generate coverage report in html file.

I know we have a command

```
coverage html --include=myproject/*.*
```

It generates a 'htmlcov' folder inside my project directory where we can find all app/files coverage report in html format individually. but I want only one html file (or you can say index.html file which is inside htmlcov folder) which give me project's coverage. I dont want to generate all files. How to do that using coverage.? or Is there any other good approach using that I can generate my unit test coverage report in single html file.?

Comment: Is the index.html file the thing you are looking for?  Or do you want all of the behavior of all of the individual html files, but jammed into one enormous file?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yes, I want  all of the behavior of all of the individual html files, but jammed into one enormous file. How to do that? I also wnat the number of errors and success with detail in a single file with explaination after running my test cases.

Comment: coverage.py doesn't provide a way to make one html file with all the reports.  Perhaps a generic bundle-a-site-into-a-file package can do it?

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Is there any package ? Also I want to know method/package how to create file after running my test cases which contains all info about tests. Like number of errors, success and there detail. Is there any method to do that?

Comment: This would actually be a nice thing to have: my CI server only allows a finite number of "artifacts" to be saved, and this is less than the number of files that is generated by `coverage html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a mostly-complete implementation of this. It's fairly tightly tied to the `coverage html` output at this stage. It is non-destructive, although if you happened to have a file `htmlcov/coverage.html`, then it would overwrite that.

```
import codecs
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scripts = []
styles = []
bodies = []
processed = []


def explode(filename):
    # We want to turn the body element into a div so we can use it
    # in one page with all of the other body elements.
    processed.append(filename)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8'))
    body = soup.body
    body.name = 'div'
    body['id'] = filename
    body['class'] = 'body'
    bodies.append(body)

    # Ensure that we grab all of the scripts that are required by
    # this page.
    for script in soup.find_all('script'):
        if 'src' in script.attrs:
            content = codecs.open(script['src'], encoding='utf-8').read()
        else:
            content = script.string
        if content not in scripts:
            scripts.append(content)

    # Likewise for the link[stylesheet] elements.
    for link in soup.find_all('link'):
        content = codecs.open(link['href'], encoding='utf-8').read()
        if content not in styles:
            styles.append(content)

    for a in soup.find_all('a'):
        # Make sure all local-links are rewritten to point to a more
        # fully-qualified name (these are line number links).
        if a['href'][0] == '#':
            anchor = u'{}-{}'.format(filename, a['href'][1:])

            a['href'] = u'#{}'.format(anchor)
            a.parent['id'] = anchor
        elif a['href'] in processed:
            # Pages we have already seen, we want to have a local link.
            a['href'] = u'#{}'.format(a['href'])
        else:
            # Otherwise, we want to see if we have a file that matches
            # the href, and embed that. Yay recursion.
            try:
                explode(a['href'])
            except IOError:
                pass
            else:
                a['href'] = u'#{}'.format(a['href'])


TEMPLATE = u'''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Coverage report</title>
    <style>{styles}</style>
    <script>{scripts}</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {body}
  </body>
</html>
'''

# Fire off the tree walking with htmlcov/index.html
os.chdir('htmlcov')
explode('index.html')

# Override the toggle_lines function to limit it to just our code block.
scripts.append('''
coverage.toggle_lines = function (btn, cls) {
    btn = $(btn);
    var hide = "hide_"+cls;
    if (btn.hasClass(hide)) {
        btn.closest('.body').find("#source ."+cls).removeClass(hide);
        btn.removeClass(hide);
    }
    else {
        $("#source ."+cls).addClass(hide);
        btn.addClass(hide);
    }
};
''')

result = TEMPLATE.format(
    styles=u'\n'.join(styles),
    scripts=u'\n'.join(scripts),
    body=u'\n'.join([unicode(x) for x in bodies])
)

codecs.open('coverage.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(result)
os.chdir('..')
```